# Shiny Event Observer Freezes with New User Selection

Tags: r, sql-server, shiny

I am building a Shiny app that provides canned reports and maps from a database of field-collected vegetation data.  The app has a series of SQL scripts that draw in the data from appropriate database tables to generate the reports and to query the spatial data stored as blobs.  The user interface allows the user to select a project and then a unit within that project on which to report. When my app runs, Shiny freezes when I try to change one of the projects.  I suspect that this has to do either with how I have set up the reactivity to update the "Unit" drop down menu, or the interface between R and MS SQL.  Unfortunately, I was unable to recreate the problem outside of my organization's enterprise data, so I will present two scripts which will hopefully be enough information.  My apologies ahead of time for not being able to come up with a script that reproduces the error.  Below is a working minimal reproducible example of how I have structured the app - this one works without error, but will give you a sense of how I have built the app and how it should work:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plyr)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

Projects<-c("Test", "Test", "Example", "Example", "Exhibit B", "Exhibit B")
Units<-c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2")
CHOICE<-data.frame(PROJECTS = Projects, UNITS = Units)

P1<-sample(Projects, 100, replace=TRUE)
U1<-sample(Units, 100, replace=TRUE)
V1<-runif(100, 44.000, 45.900)
V2<-runif(100, -120.5, -118.0)

Data<-data.frame(Project = P1, Unit = U1, Value_1 = V1, Value_2 = V2)

ui<-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Example_UI"),
  dashboardSidebar(
                selectInput(inputId = "Prj", "Select a Project", choices = unique(CHOICE$PROJECTS), selected = unique(CHOICE$PROJECTS)[1]),
                selectInput(inputId = "Unit", "Select a Unit", choices = NULL)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tmapOutput(outputId = "map"),
    tableOutput(outputId = "TABLE")
  )
)

server<-function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$Prj,{
    updateSelectInput(session, "Unit", 
                      choices = unique(CHOICE$UNITS[CHOICE$PROJECTS==input$Prj]), 
                      selected = unique(CHOICE$UNITS[CHOICE$PROJECTS==input$Prj])[1])
  })
  output$TABLE<-renderTable({
    Data2<-subset(Data, Project == input$Prj & Unit == input$Unit)
    tbl<-ddply(Data2, c("Project", "Unit"), summarize, VALUE = max(Value_1), OTHER_VALUE=mean(Value_2))
    return(tbl)
  })
  output$map<-renderTmap({
    Data2<-subset(Data, Project == input$Prj & Unit == input$Unit)
    WGS84<-CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
    Pts<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(Data2[,c(4,3)], Data2[,c(1:2)], proj4string = WGS84)
    tmap_mode("view")
    tm_shape(Pts)+
      tm_dots("Project")+
      tm_basemap(server=providers$Esri.WorldImagery)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This next script is my actual app, which freezes.  As I mentioned above, I suspect this behavior is a result of either the `observeEvent()` call in the server function, or the interface between R and MS SQL.  I have been able to rule out any of the `render*()` functions, by commenting them out in the server function as well as their corresponding `*output()` calls in the UI function. Because this requires several SQL scripts and enterprise data, it won't be able to be run independently, but I am including it to see if any obvious code error jumps out:

```
####Shiny Test Page####
##Loading Packages##
library(shiny) #For making web application
library(DBI) #For connecting to databases
library(odbc) #For querying database
library(shinydashboard) #For web layout design functions
library(readr) #For reading SQL scripts
library(sf) #For reading Well-Known binary geometries from TFM database and GIS capabilities
library(rgeos) #For other GIS capabilities
library(tmap) #For creating web map
library(knitr) #For downloading reports generated
library(rmarkdown) #For downloading reports generated
library(kableExtra) #For creating and formatting tables
library(gsubfn) #For SQL Queries with multiple elements for a WHERE clause

####Getting SQL REPORTS####
##Connecting to databases##
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), dsn = "Instance1", database = "Database1")
con2 <- dbConnect(odbc(), dsn="Instance2", database = "Database2")

##Setting Working Directory to SQL Script Folder##
setwd("//Path/to/MyDirectory/")

##Creating Object of available units for WHERE clause##
units_full<-dbGetQuery(conn=con, "SELECT P.project_id, PR.project_name, SUB.unit_objectid,SUB.sale_objectid, P.fma_id, P.unit_name_user, P.punit_id FROM sf_tris.fma_walt_subunits SUB
  JOIN sf_tris.fma_walt_sale_units SU
  ON SU.unit_objectid = SUB.unit_objectid
  JOIN sf_tris.project_punit P
  ON P.fma_id = SU.unit_objectid
  JOIN sf_tris.project PR
  ON PR.project_id = P.project_id")

PLOT_TEST<-dbGetQuery(conn=con, "SELECT distinct(fma_id) FROM sf_tris.project_punit P
JOIN sf_tris.project_plot U
ON P.punit_id = U.punit_id")

units<-unique(units_full[units_full$fma_id %in% PLOT_TEST$fma_id,])

####Reading in SQL Scripts for Report Data####
LST_SQL<-read_file(paste(getwd(), "LOGSTOCK", "LOGSTOCKTABLE_FULL_project.sql", sep="/")) #FROM INVENTORY_PLANT
SSG_SQL<-read_file(paste(getwd(), "SORTGRADE", "SORTGRADE_FULL_project.sql", sep="/")) #FROM INVENTORY_PLANT
ST_SQL<-read_file(paste(getwd(), "STANDTABLE", "STANDTABLE_project.sql", sep="/")) #FROM INVENTORY_PLANT 
SS_SQL<-read_file(paste(getwd(), "STANDTABLE", "STANDSUMMARYTABLES_project.sql", sep="/")) #FROM INVENTORY_PLANT
CZ_SQL<-read_file(paste(getwd(), "CRUISE", "CRUISE.sql", sep="/")) #From TFM 
TFM_SQL<-read_file(paste(getwd(), "TFM", "TFM_INFO.sql", sep="/")) #From TFM 

####User Interface###
ui<-dashboardPage( # Start Dashboard Page
  dashboardHeader(title = "REPORTING SERVICE"), #Dashboard  Header
  dashboardSidebar( #Start  Dashboard Sidebar
    sidebarMenu(tabName="REPORTS", # Start Sidebar Menu
                menuItem("REPORT OPTIONS", tabName="REPORTS", # Start Menu Item
                         radioButtons(inputId = "REPORT", label="Available Reports",
                                      choices=c("Species, Sort, and Grade", "Log Stock Table", "Stand Table", "Stand Summary", "Cruise Report")),#End RadioButtons
                         selectizeInput(inputId="PROJECT", 
                                     label="SELECT A Project", choices = unique(units$project_name), selected = units$project_name[1]
                                     ),#End Selected Items List
                         selectizeInput(inputId="UNIT", 
                                     label="SELECT A UNIT", choices = NULL),#End Selected Items List
                         downloadButton(outputId="rpt_dwnld", "Download Report")
                )#End Menu Item
    )#End SidebarMenu
  ),#End Dashboard Sidebar
  dashboardBody(#tableOutput(outputId = "OUT_REPORT")
    textOutput(outputId ="STAND"),
    textOutput(outputId = "SEL_REPORT"),
    textOutput(outputId = "PLSS"),
    textOutput(outputId = "SUBUNIT"),
    tmapOutput(outputId = "MAP"),
    tableOutput(outputId = "TABLE")
  ) # DashboardBody
) # End Dashboard Page

####Server Function####
server<-function(input, output, session){
  
  ##Metadata outout##
  observeEvent(input$PROJECT,{
         updateSelectizeInput(session, 
                        "UNIT", 
                        choices = units$fma_id[units$project_name==input$PROJECT], 
                        selected = units$fma_id[units$project_name==input$PROJECT][1]
                        )
    })
  output$STAND<-renderText({ 
    paste("SELECTED PROJECT:", input$PROJECT, sep=" ")})
  output$SUBUNIT<-renderText({
    UNT<-input$UNIT
    paste("SELECTED STAND:", UNT, sep=" ")})
  output$SEL_REPORT<-renderText({paste("SELECTED REPORT:", input$REPORT, sep=" ")})
    output$PLSS<-renderText({
    fma<-input$UNIT
    TFM_Query<-paste(TFM_SQL, "\r\nWHERE A.SUOID =",  fma, "\r\n\r\n", sep=" ")
    TFM_PLSS<-dbGetQuery(con2, TFM_Query)
    paste("PLSS DESCRIPTION:", unique(TFM_PLSS$PLS_Description))})

  ####Map output####
 output$MAP<-renderTmap({
    
    #Projects Used#
    ORLAMB<-CRS("+init=epsg:2992")
    WGS84<-CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
    
    #Getting Selection Criteria for Polygons#
    fma<-input$UNIT
    SU.where<-toString(unique(units$sale_objectid[units$project_name==input$PROJECT]))
    SSU.where<-toString(unique(units$fma_id[units$fma_id==input$UNIT]))
  
    #Creating SQL Queries for Spatial Data#
    SU<-fn$dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT sale_objectid, geom.STAsBinary() AS SU from sf_tris.fma_walt_sale_units SU WHERE SU.sale_objectid in ($SU.where)")
    SSU<-fn$dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT unit_objectid, geom.STAsBinary() AS SSU from sf_tris.fma_walt_subunits SSU WHERE SSU.unit_objectid in ($SSU.where)")
    
    #Converting from Well-known binary to sf#
   poly.SSU<-st_as_sfc(SSU$SSU, EWKB=FALSE)
   poly.SU<-st_as_sfc(SU$SU, EWKB=FALSE)
    
   poly.SSU2<-st_as_sf(poly.SSU)
   poly.SU2<-st_as_sf(poly.SU)
    
    #Defining projects#
    st_crs(poly.SSU2)<-WGS84
    st_crs(poly.SU2)<-WGS84
    
    #Creating Mapping interface#
    tmap_mode("view")
    tm_shape(poly.SSU2, name="UNIT") +
      tm_polygons(col="yellow", alpha=0.5, border.col="gray") +
      tm_shape(poly.SU2, name="PROJECT")+
      tm_polygons(col="gray", alpha=0.5, border.col="darkgray") +
            tm_basemap(server=providers$Esri.WorldImagery)+
      tm_add_legend("fill", col=c("yellow", "darkgray"), 
                    border.col = "grey40", labels=c("Unit", "Project"))
    
  })
  
  ####Table Output####  
  output$TABLE<-function(){#Start Kable Function
    req(input$REPORT)#attaching reactive value for requested report
    REPORTS<-data.frame(REPORT=c("Species, Sort, and Grade", "Log Stock Table", "Stand Table", "Stand Summary", "Cruise Report"),
                        SQL=c("SSG", "LST", "ST", "SS", "CZ"))#Crosswalk between UI report values and SQL report values
    
    #Getting selction values#
    RPT<-REPORTS$SQL[REPORTS$REPORT==input$REPORT]
    fma<-input$UNIT
      
    #Pasting in WHERE clause and ORDER clause#
    LST_Query<-paste0(LST_SQL, "\r\nWHERE D.fma_id =", "'" , fma,  "'"," \r\nORDER BY SPECIES, SORT, GRADE \r\n\r\n")
    SSG_Query<-paste0(SSG_SQL, "\r\nWHERE A.fma_id =", "'", fma, "'",  " \r\nORDER BY SPECIES \r\n\r\n")
    ST_Query<-paste0(ST_SQL, "\r\nWHERE U.fma_id =", "'", fma, "'",  " \r\nORDER BY U.punit_id, SPECIES \r\n\r\n")
    SS_Query<-paste0(SS_SQL, "\r\nWHERE A.fma_id =", "'", fma, "'", " \r\nORDER BY SPECIES, DBH \r\n\r\n")
    CZ_Query<-paste0(CZ_SQL, "\r\nWHERE C.UNIT =",  fma, " ORDER BY HarvestType \r\n\r\n")
    
    #Running Queries# 
    LST<-dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement = LST_Query)
    SSG<-dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement = SSG_Query)
    ST<-dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement = ST_Query)
    SS<-dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement = SS_Query)
    CZ<-dbGetQuery(conn=con2, statement = CZ_Query)
    
    ##Building "Kables" for table output## 
    #Log Stock Table#
    colnames(LST)<-c("Unit", "FMA","Species", "Sort", "Grade", "Gross MBF", "Net MBF",
                     "Percent Defect", "0 - 1", "2 - 3", "4 - 5", "6 - 7", 
                     "8 - 9", "10 - 11", "12 - 13", "14 - 15", "16 - 19",
                     "20 - 23", "24 - 29", "30 - 39", "40 +" )
    LST_tbl<-knitr::kable(LST[,-c(1,2)],  format="html", align=c('l', rep('c', ncol(LST)-2))) %>%
      kable_classic(font_size = 14) %>%
      kable_styling(full_width=FALSE) %>% 
      column_spec(1:6, width_max="0.5cm") %>% 
      column_spec(7:(ncol(LST)-2), width_min = "1cm") %>% 
      add_header_above(header=c(" " = 6, "Net Board Feet by Log Diameter (in)" = 13))
    
    #Species Sort and Grade#
    colnames(SSG)<-c("FMA", "Species", "Sort", "Grade", 
                    "Defect","Net", "Gross", "Net Board Feet",
                     "4 - 5", "6 - 11", "12 - 16", "17 +",
                     "11 - 20", "21 - 30", "31 - 35", "39 - 99", "Average Length",
                     "Average Diameter", "Average Board Feet", "Average Cubic Feet", "Logs")
    SSG[,6]<-paste(as.character(SSG[,6]),"%")
    SSG_tbl<-knitr::kable(SSG[,-c(1,5)], format="html") %>% 
      kable_classic(font_size = 14) %>% 
      kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)  %>% 
      column_spec(1:7, width="0.5cm") %>% 
      column_spec(8:17, width="1.5cm") %>% 
      column_spec(18:(ncol(SSG)-2), width = "0.5cm") %>% 
      add_header_above(header=c(" "= 4, "Volume in Board Feet Per Acre" =3,"Net Board Feet by Log Diameter (in)" = 4, "Net Board Feet by Log Length (ft)" = 4, " " = 5))
    
    #Stand Table#
    colnames(ST)<-c("Unit ID", "FMA","Unit Name", "Species", "Trees per Acre", "Sample Trees",
                    "Average DBH", "Bole Length", "Net Board Feet per Acre", "Gross Board Feet per Acre",
                    "Net Cubic Feet per Acre", "Gross Cubic Feet per Acre", "Basal Area", "Plots")
    ST_tbl<-knitr::kable(ST[,-c(1:3)], format="html") %>% 
      kable_classic(font_size = 14) %>% 
      kable_styling(full_width = TRUE)  %>% 
      column_spec(1:6, width_min="0.5cm") %>% 
      column_spec(7:(ncol(ST)-3), width_min = "1cm")
    
    #Stand Summary#
    colnames(SS)<-c("Unit ID", "FMA", "Unit Name", "Species", "DBH", "Tree Count",
                    "Plots", "Form Factor", "Height", "Basal Area per Acre",
                    "Logs per Acre","Average Net Cubic Feet", "Average Net Board Feet",
                    "Cubic Feet per Acre", "Board Feet per Acre", "Cunit", "MBF")
    SS_tbl<-knitr::kable(SS[,-c(1:3)], format="html") %>% 
      kable_classic(font_size = 14)  %>% 
      kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)  %>% 
      column_spec(1:6, width_min="0.5cm") %>% 
      column_spec(7:(ncol(SS)-3), width_min = "1cm")
    
    #Cruising Report#
    colnames(CZ)[2:3]<-c("Harvest Type", "Gross Acres")
    CZ_tbl<-knitr::kable(CZ[,-1], format="html") %>% 
      kable_classic(font_size = 10) %>% 
      kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
    
    #Outputting kable#  
    OUT<-list(LST_tbl, SSG_tbl, ST_tbl, SS_tbl, CZ_tbl)
    names(OUT)<-c("LST", "SSG", "ST", "SS", "CZ")
    kables(OUT[RPT])
    }#End Kable
  
  ####Creating downloadable table output####
  output$rpt_dwnld<-downloadHandler(#Start download Handler
    
    filename = function(){
      fname<-input$REPORT
      paste(fname, "Report.pdf", sep="_")}, 
    
    content <-function(file){#Start content function
      
      #Getting selction values#
      req(input$REPORT)#attaching reactive value for requested report
      REPORTS<-data.frame(REPORT=c("Species, Sort, and Grade", "Log Stock Table", "Stand Table", "Stand Summary", "Cruise Report"),
                          SQL=c("SSG", "LST", "ST", "SS", "CZ"))#Crosswalk between UI report values and SQL report values
      
      #Getting selction values#
      RPT<-REPORTS$SQL[REPORTS$REPORT==input$REPORT]
      RPT2<-input$REPORT
      PROJECT<-input$PROJECT
      fma<-input$UNIT
      
      #Pasting in WHERE clause and ORDER clause#
      LST_Query<-paste0(LST_SQL, "\r\nWHERE D.fma_id =", "'" , fma,  "'"," \r\nORDER BY SPECIES, SORT, GRADE \r\n\r\n")
      SSG_Query<-paste0(SSG_SQL, "\r\nWHERE DIA.fma_id =", "'", fma, "'",  " \r\nORDER BY SPECIES \r\n\r\n")
      ST_Query<-paste0(ST_SQL, "\r\nWHERE U.fma_id =", "'", fma, "'",  " \r\nORDER BY F.punit_id, F.SPECIES \r\n\r\n")
      SS_Query<-paste0(SS_SQL, "\r\nWHERE A.fma_id =", "'", fma, "'", " \r\nORDER BY SPECIES, DBH \r\n\r\n")
      CZ_Query<-paste0(CZ_SQL, "\r\nWHERE C.UNIT =",  fma, " ORDER BY HarvestType \r\n\r\n")
      
      #Running Queries# 
      LST<-dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement = LST_Query)
      SSG<-dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement = SSG_Query)
      ST<-dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement = ST_Query)
      SS<-dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement = SS_Query)
      CZ<-dbGetQuery(conn=con2, statement = CZ_y)
      
      ##Building "Kables" for table output## 
      #Log Stock Table#
      colnames(LST)<-c("Unit", "FMA","Species", "Sort", "Grade", "Gross MBF", "Net MBF",
                       "Percent Defect", "0 - 1", "2 - 3", "4 - 5", "6 - 7", 
                       "8 - 9", "10 - 11", "12 - 13", "14 - 15", "16 - 19",
                       "20 - 23", "24 - 29", "30 - 39", "40 +" )
      LST_tbl<-knitr::kable(LST[,-c(1,2)],  format="html", align=c('l', rep('c', ncol(LST)-2))) %>%
        kable_classic(font_size = 14) %>%
        kable_styling(full_width=FALSE) %>% 
        column_spec(1:6, width_max="0.5cm") %>% 
        column_spec(7:(ncol(LST)-2), width_min = "1cm") %>% 
        add_header_above(header=c(" " = 6, "Net Board Feet by Log Diameter (in)" = 13))
      
      #Species Sort and Grade#
      colnames(SSG)<-c("FMA", "Species", "Sort", "Grade", 
                       "Defect","Net", "Gross", "Net Board Feet",
                       "4 - 5", "6 - 11", "12 - 16", "17 +",
                       "11 - 20", "21 - 30", "31 - 35", "39 - 99", "Average Length",
                       "Average Diameter", "Average Board Feet", "Average Cubic Feet", "Logs")
      SSG[,6]<-paste(as.character(SSG[,6]),"%")
      SSG_tbl<-knitr::kable(SSG[,-c(1,5)], format="html") %>% 
        kable_classic(font_size = 14) %>% 
        kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)  %>% 
        column_spec(1:7, width="0.5cm") %>% 
        column_spec(8:17, width="1.5cm") %>% 
        column_spec(18:(ncol(SSG)-2), width = "0.5cm") %>% 
        add_header_above(header=c(" "= 4, "Volume in Board Feet Per Acre" =3,"Net Board Feet by Log Diameter (in)" = 4, "Net Board Feet by Log Length (ft)" = 4, " " = 5))
      
      
      #Stand Table#
      colnames(ST)<-c("Unit ID", "FMA","Unit Name", "Species", "Trees per Acre", "Sample Trees",
                      "Average DBH", "Bole Length", "Net Board Feet per Acre", "Gross Board Feet per Acre",
                      "Net Cubic Feet per Acre", "Gross Cubic Feet per Acre", "Basal Area", "Plots")
      ST_tbl<-knitr::kable(ST[,-c(1:3)], format="html") %>% 
        kable_classic(font_size = 14) %>% 
        kable_styling(full_width = TRUE)  %>% 
        column_spec(1:6, width_min="0.5cm") %>% 
        column_spec(7:(ncol(ST)-3), width_min = "1cm")
      
      #Stand Summary#
      colnames(SS)<-c("Unit ID", "FMA", "Unit Name", "Species", "DBH", "Tree Count",
                      "Plots", "Form Factor", "Height", "Basal Area per Acre",
                      "Logs per Acre","Average Net Cubic Feet", "Average Net Board Feet",
                      "Cubic Feet per Acre", "Board Feet per Acre", "Cunit", "MBF")
      SS_tbl<-knitr::kable(SS[,-c(1:3)], format="html") %>% 
        kable_classic(font_size = 14)  %>% 
        kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)  %>% 
        column_spec(1:6, width_min="0.5cm") %>% 
        column_spec(7:(ncol(SS)-3), width_min = "1cm")
      
      #Cruising Report#
      colnames(CZ)[2:3]<-c("Harvest Type", "Gross Acres")
      CZ_tbl<-knitr::kable(CZ[,-1], format="html") %>% 
        kable_classic(font_size = 10) %>% 
        kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
      
      #Selecting Kable for output#
      OUT<-list(LST_tbl, SSG_tbl, ST_tbl, SS_tbl, CZ_tbl)
      names(OUT)<-c("LST", "SSG", "ST", "SS", "CZ")
      TABLE<-OUT[RPT]
      
      #Getting parameters to pass to TFM query#
      fma<-input$UNIT
      TFM_Query<-paste0(TFM_SQL, "\r\nWHERE A.SUOID =",  fma, "\r\n\r\n")
      TFM_PLSS<-dbGetQuery(con2, TFM_Query)
      PLSS<-TFM_PLSS$PLS_Description
      
      #Passing arguments to Rmarkdown to create pdf#
      tmp<-normalizePath("report.Rmd")
      owd<-setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(tmp, "report.Rmd", overwrite=TRUE)
      params<-list(RPT2, PROJECT, PLSS, TABLE)
      names(params)<-c("RPT2", "PROJECT", "PLSS", "TABLE")
      out<-rmarkdown::render("report.Rmd",
                             params = params,
                             envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()
                             ))#End render
      file.rename(out,file)
    }#Close content function
  )#End downloadHandler
}#End Server Function

####Launch Shiny App####
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.  Again, I apologize that my reproducible example doesn't trigger the error, but I can't recreate the error outside of enterprise level data.  Thanks so much.
Take Care,
-Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with an SQL script that I read into my Shiny server function.  It was a lesson in making sure all helping scripts are running properly before sourcing them into Shiny.